# I can't put anything into else or else if in c# after the if

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Calculator";
            Console.WindowHeight = 40;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            string answer2;
            string answer;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to multiply?");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (answer == "yes");
            {
            
             double num01;
             double num02;

             Console.Write("Please input the first number for multiplication: ");
             num01 = Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine() );

             Console.Write("Now input the other number, please: ");
             num02 = Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine() );
             
             double result = num01 * num02;
             Console.WriteLine("The result is " + result + "!");
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        
            
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive with what problem you are experiencing?

Comment: There's a semicolon after `if (answer == "yes")`. Remove that and the `else` should become valid.

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong

```
if (answer == "yes");
```

should be

```
if (answer == "yes")
```